# How to speed up DataTable in memory

Tags: arrays, vb.net, datatables

Why is a DataTable so slow comparing to arrays operations?
I am doing some operations on a DataTable in memory. I was surprised by the low speed of calculations, so I did some comparison tests between a DataTable and an array. I found two things that puzzle me:

1. The speed of the DataTable decreases with the number of columns: I added 30 empty columns, and the speed decreased 8 times.
2. The most taxing part of the routine is writing the values in the DataTable: reading from DataTable to an array was `124ms`, calculating the array was `7ms`, and writing from array back to DataTable was `1127ms`. Calculating directly in the DataTable, I got `1189ms`, which is slightly less than the total operating thru array `1234ms`.

Can somebody help me speed up the DataTable operation? The calculations are more complicated in my real application with some trig, log, and exponent. Therefore I cannot use formulas in the definition of the DataTable columns.

Here is the code I used:

```
'Checks what is the fastest: dataTable or array
Dim multiply As Integer = 1_000_000
Dim j As Integer

Dim item0(multiply) As Single
Dim item1(multiply) As Single
Dim item2(multiply) As Single

Dim myTable As DataTable = New DataTable("TestSpeed")
myTable.Columns.Add("item0", Type.GetType("System.Single"))
myTable.Columns.Add("item1", Type.GetType("System.Single"))
myTable.Columns.Add("item2", Type.GetType("System.Single"))

'Those columns are empty
myTable.Columns.Add("item3", Type.GetType("System.Single"))
myTable.Columns.Add("item4", Type.GetType("System.Single"))
myTable.Columns.Add("item5", Type.GetType("System.Single"))
myTable.Columns.Add("item6", Type.GetType("System.Single"))
myTable.Columns.Add("item7", Type.GetType("System.Single"))
myTable.Columns.Add("item8", Type.GetType("System.Single"))
myTable.Columns.Add("item9", Type.GetType("System.Single"))

myTable.Columns.Add("itemA", Type.GetType("System.String"))
myTable.Columns.Add("itemB", Type.GetType("System.String"))
myTable.Columns.Add("itemC", Type.GetType("System.String"))
myTable.Columns.Add("itemD", Type.GetType("System.String"))
myTable.Columns.Add("itemE", Type.GetType("System.String"))
myTable.Columns.Add("itemF", Type.GetType("System.String"))
myTable.Columns.Add("itemG", Type.GetType("System.String"))
myTable.Columns.Add("itemH", Type.GetType("System.String"))
myTable.Columns.Add("itemI", Type.GetType("System.String"))
myTable.Columns.Add("itemJ", Type.GetType("System.String"))
myTable.Columns.Add("itemK", Type.GetType("System.String"))
myTable.Columns.Add("itemL", Type.GetType("System.String"))
myTable.Columns.Add("itemM", Type.GetType("System.String"))
myTable.Columns.Add("itemN", Type.GetType("System.String"))
myTable.Columns.Add("itemO", Type.GetType("System.String"))
myTable.Columns.Add("itemP", Type.GetType("System.String"))
myTable.Columns.Add("itemQ", Type.GetType("System.String"))
myTable.Columns.Add("itemR", Type.GetType("System.String"))
myTable.Columns.Add("itemS", Type.GetType("System.String"))
myTable.Columns.Add("itemT", Type.GetType("System.String"))
myTable.Columns.Add("itemU", Type.GetType("System.String"))
myTable.Columns.Add("itemV", Type.GetType("System.String"))
myTable.Columns.Add("itemW", Type.GetType("System.String"))
myTable.Columns.Add("itemX", Type.GetType("System.String"))
myTable.Columns.Add("itemY", Type.GetType("System.String"))
myTable.Columns.Add("itemZ", Type.GetType("System.String"))

Dim myNewRow As DataRow

'Populate the table
For j = 0 To multiply - 1
    myNewRow = myTable.NewRow
    myNewRow("item1") = 21.1F
    myNewRow("item2") = 27.3F
    myTable.Rows.Add(myNewRow)
Next
myTable.AcceptChanges()

Dim timeStart As DateTime = Now

'Calculate the table by itself
For Each myRow As DataRow In myTable.Rows
    myRow("item0") = Convert.ToSingle(myRow("item1")) + Convert.ToSingle(myRow("item2"))
Next
Dim tableTime As DateTime = Now

'Copy the relevant table to the array
j = 0
For Each myRow As DataRow In myTable.Rows
    item1(j) = Convert.ToSingle(myRow("item1"))
    item2(j) = Convert.ToSingle(myRow("item2"))
    j = +1
Next
Dim arrayReadTime As DateTime = Now

'Calculate the array
For j = 0 To myTable.Rows.Count - 1
    item0(j) = item1(j) + item2(j)
Next
Dim arrayCalcTime As DateTime = Now

'Write the array in the DataTable
j = 0
For Each myRow As DataRow In myTable.Rows
    myRow("item0") = item0(j)
    j = +1
Next
Dim arrayWriteTime As DateTime = Now

MsgBox("Table TOTAL " & (tableTime - timeStart).ToString & vbCrLf & vbCrLf &
       "Array Read  " & (arrayReadTime - tableTime).ToString & vbCrLf &
       "Array Calc  " & (arrayCalcTime - arrayReadTime).ToString & vbCrLf &
       "Array Write " & (arrayWriteTime - arrayCalcTime).ToString & vbCrLf &
       "Array TOTAL " & (arrayWriteTime - tableTime).ToString & vbCrLf & vbCrLf &
       "Difference  " & ((arrayWriteTime - tableTime) - (tableTime - timeStart)).ToString)
```

Comment: DataTable object does a lot of things behind the scene, you can check out here https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=Datatable . The better way is to compute things using low level objects like array.

Comment: @vikas or any other data structure in LINQ

Comment: @vikas, thank you for the comment. Can you please recommend some areas where I can do some research on filtering/sorting arrays (the main thing I need the DataTable for)? Up to now, the only choice I can see is HashTable. Do you have any other alternatives?

Comment: You can also try using `myRow.BeginEdit()` before calculating and `myRow.EndEdit()` after. This disables [row events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.beginedit?view=net-5.0) etc.

Comment: Define a class with the properties that map to your datatable, then create a list of instances of that class.  From there it's just simple linq (although that can be done on a DataTable) to do the filtering/sorting.

Comment: @Hursey, thank you for the suggestion. I intend to do a combination of some HashTables for various sortings and an array of a class that has the columns of the table.

Comment: @AlexB., It is an excellent trick. I will remember it. It speeds up the calculation approx 3 times.   Here something interesting: using your idea on the reading to array part of the program required more time by15%. But if I used it only in the write back to the table from the array, it is 30-40% faster than if I do not do the arrays at all. Thank you.

Comment: You can also play with `DataTable.BeginLoadData` [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.beginloaddata?view=net-5.0) which is especially worth when using also `DataTable.LoadDataRow` [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.loaddatarow?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @AlexB., I tried it, but it didn't help at the point of calculation, but it speeds up a little the table's loading. Maybe if I had a more complicated DataTable, with some formulas or some connections to other tables, this would have a higher effect at initialization. Thank you for the suggestion.